# Contextual action in a ListView forces Adapters getView on every click

Tags: android, android-listview, android-adapter

I have a ListFragment (for compatibility reasons I use android.support.v4.app.ListFragment) and want to use the contextual action mode.

Therefore I coded:

```
public class CustomListFragment extends ListFragment {
...
    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
        setListAdapter(new CustomListAdapter(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), TYPE));

        if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB){
             registerForContextMenu(getListView());
        } else {
            getListView().setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE_MODAL);
            getListView().setMultiChoiceModeListener(new CustomMultiSpamItemChoiceModeListener());          
        }
   }
...
}


class CustomMultiSpamItemChoiceModeListener implements MultiChoiceModeListener{
    @Override
    public boolean onActionItemClicked(ActionMode arg0, MenuItem arg1) {
        return false;
    }
    @Override
    public boolean onCreateActionMode(ActionMode arg0, Menu arg1) {
        return false;
    }
    @Override
    public void onDestroyActionMode(ActionMode arg0) {
    }
    @Override
    public boolean onPrepareActionMode(ActionMode arg0, Menu arg1) {
        return false;
    }
    @Override
    public void onItemCheckedStateChanged(ActionMode arg0, int arg1,
            long arg2, boolean arg3) {
    }
}


public class CustomListAdapter extends BaseAdapter{
...
    @Override
    public View getView(int pos, View view, ViewGroup vg) {
    ...
    }
}
```

The problem is that as soon as I set the **`setChoiceMode`** to **`ListView.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE_MODAL`** the adapters method **`getView(int pos, View view, ViewGroup vg)`**
is called on every click (*short pressed click*) on an item of the `ListView`. The contextual action mode isn't even activated.

This become manifest in a long lasting item pressed animation.
Normally the blue indicator for an item pressed lasts a few ms but in my case its about a second because it takes some time to collect all needed information to create the ListItems.

Is this behavior as expected? 
I don't think the **`ListView.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE_MODAL`** flag needs to "reinitiate" the whole `ListItems` again.

Comment: Did you managed to fix it?